# Merging two tables in Hive with data validation

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two tables with some similar columns. Say,
`Table X` has `id,first_name last_name`.
`Table Y` has `id,email_id, first_name`.

However both these tables are imperfect, so I need to fill in the null values in both the tables from the data in the other table(using some key(id in the eg)) and push it to another table.

How can I do this efficiently ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join the tables and then write a `case` statement.

**Example 0**:

```
select x.id as id
  , case when x.first_name is null then y.first_name else x.first_name end as first_name
  , x.last_name as last_name
  , y.email_id as email_id
from db.tableX x
join db.tableY y
on y.id = x.id
```

or you could do pretty much the same but with an `if` statement.

**Example 1**:

```
select x.id as id
  , if(x.first_name is null, y.first_name, x.first_name) as first_name
  , x.last_name as last_name
  , y.email_id as email_id
from db.tableX x
join db.tableY y
on y.id = x.id
```